# Typescript: how to get private properties from class type?

Tags: angular, typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

Is it posible that using generics I could check for the private/protected keys on a class?

This is my code:

```js
export type SubjectListenerCloneTypeFrom<T, N extends keyof T> = UnPromisify<
  ClassReturnType<T, N>
>;
```

But with that, `create` that is the private method, does not show up

[image]

Comment: Nope, keyof is only for public members

Comment: Yep I know with `keyof ` I can't get them. But is any other way to get it? other keyword or something?

Comment: Nope... Keyof is the only way to get fields, and keyof does not work with privates...

Comment: So is it correct that for my private methods of a class I get autocomple with the "string index notation": `classInstance["privateMethod"]`.
But it is not possible to create a type or a type check that only available private methods of a class can be used?